# Use only ExoPlayer's controller for playing audio in Android without the black preview

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

I want to play a list of audio files in android. As you might know, when you have video files, using the `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView` does make sense because you can see the content of the video on the screen while you have the controller for play/pause etc. on the bottom.
But with audio files, you have a black screen if you let play the audio files.
What I need is to use only the controller without the black screen.

Is there a way to do that ?

1st **EDIT**:
In the documentation, I came across `PlaybackControlView` and `PlayerControlView`. Can I use them for my situation ? If yes, which one to use ?

2nd **EDIT**: Here are my results after 1 day of research. I used `PlaybackControlView` in my layout like this:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlaybackControlView
      android:id="@+id/play_back_control_view"
      android:layout_width="0dp"        <--- I use ConstraintLayout, so this is okay
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/black"
      android:alpha="0.15"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_playback_control_view" />
```

As you might see from the layout above, I use a custom layout for this called `custom_playback_control_view.xml`. Here is the my custom layout content:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_play"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <View
        android:id="@id/exo_progress_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="26dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/exo_duration"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/exo_play"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/exo_duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/exo_progress_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Last but not least, I attached the `ExoPlayer` to the `PlaybackControlView` like this in my Fragment:

```
myAudioPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context)
binding.playBackControlView.player = myAudioPlayer
```

Comment: Can you bit elaborate it more screen shot?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to use the controller view of the ExoPlayer for playing an audio file. That's all. Only the control bar at the bottom.

Comment: You need to implement custom controller and attach the player to your custom controller.  Can you paste your current implementation?

Comment: @crack_head: yes, of course. I added my progress as 2nd EDIT to the question section above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a custom controller like this and name it media_controller.xml. I used data binding in laout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#44000000"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/forward"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/play"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_media_forward" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backward"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_media_backward" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Next create a custom class ExpoMediaController.java like following

```
public class ExpoMediaController extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener, Player.EventListener{
 private LayoutInflater inflater;
 Player simpleExoPlayer;

 private MediaControllerBinding binding;//media_controller.xml

public ExpoMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    initView();
}


public ExpoMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    initView();
}


private void initView() {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.media_controller, this, true);
    binding.play.setOnClickListener(this);
    binding.forward.setOnClickListener(this);
    binding.backward.setOnClickListener(this);


}

//Use this method to set and unset the player
public void setPlayer(@Nullable Player simpleExoPlayer) {
    if (this.simpleExoPlayer == simpleExoPlayer) {
        return;
    }
    Player oldPlayer = this.simpleExoPlayer;//get reference of old player which attached previously
    if (oldPlayer != null) {//if old player not null then clear it
        oldPlayer.removeListener(this);
    }
    this.simpleExoPlayer = simpleExoPlayer;
    if (this.simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        this.simpleExoPlayer.addListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    switch (playbackState) {
        case STATE_BUFFERING:
            break;
        case STATE_ENDED:
            break;
        case STATE_IDLE:
            break;
        case STATE_READY:
            if (playWhenReady) {
                binding.play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_media_pause);
                binding.play.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

            } else {
                binding.play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_media_play);
                binding.play.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == binding.play && simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        if (simpleExoPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            showControls();
        } else {
            if (simpleExoPlayer.getPlaybackState() == STATE_ENDED) {
                simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
            }
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    }
}}
```

Use ExpoMediaController in your activity layout replacing com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlaybackControlView. Then call setPlayer method of ExpoMediaController. Now you have total control over controller view.